# Problems upgrading from PHP 5.1.6 to 5.2.9

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php, fedora, php5

I have a web server running Fedora Core 5 (yes, I know it's very old) and it was running PHP 5.1.6 so I downloaded and compiled the source for 5.2.9 and restarted the server and phpinfo() still returns 5.1.6.

```
$ which php
/usr/local/bin/php
```

But when I do the version switch on this PHP installation I get

```
$ /usr/local/bin/php -v
PHP 5.2.9 (cli) (built: May 26 2009 10:17:42) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2009 Zend Technologies
```

What may I have missed or how could I correct this?

Answer (score 5):

A number of things could've gone wrong. You could be loading the wrong shared library. Apache could be built with a static library of the older version of PHP. If you installed fedora with PHP/Apache support out of the box it could have the php binary in a non-standard place.

I'd first check httpd.conf to see if it's either a shared module, CGI, or statically library. If it's a shared module you need to rebuild PHP. If it's CGI then you'll just need to change the directory. If it's statically built you'll need to rebuild Apache.

Re: 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache.php

Answer (score 4):

Seems that you compiled with **`/usr/local`** prefix.

Your Apache is probably loading old PHP from it's default location. Grep though Apache `.conf` files looking for **`LoadModule php5_module`** and change it to load new module from `/usr/local`.

Answer (score 3):

You should update the new PHP module for Apache as well. Make sure to verify in `httpd.conf`.