# Problems upgrading from PHP 5.1.6 to 5.2.9

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, php5

I have a web server running CentOS 5 and it was running php 5.1.6 so I downloaded and compiled the source for 5.2.10 and restarted the server and phpinfo() still returns 5.1.6.

But when i do the version switch on this PHP i get

```
$ /usr/local/bin/php -v
PHP 5.2.9 (cli) (built: May 26 2009 10:17:42) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2009 Zend Technologies
```

There was the almost exact question [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/12210/problems-upgrading-from-php-5-1-6-to-5-2-9). Almost every answer points to addressing this by doing the following in the httpd.conf file:

```
LoadModule php5_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
```

I did that and when I restart apache I get the following:

```
Stopping httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting httpd: [Fri Sep 11 14:59:28 2009] [warn] module php5_module is already loaded, skipping
                                                           [  OK  ]
```

This obviously means that the php module is being called twice, but a search of the httpd.conf file does not reveal a second call to the module. Could php module be called from some place else? Where? Anyone have an idea what I can try next? It will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do yum remove, then update my yum repositories to include a repository with newer version of PHP and then I was able to update my PHP that way as opposed to downloading the latest PHP from the PHP website, unwrapping, and then installing.

Answer (score 0):

Look for a PHP loader in an `/etc/apache/conf.d` or `/etc/httpd/conf.d` type directory.  You can probably track down where PHP is coming in by looking through the `Include` directives in your `httpd.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the httpd.conf file, the CentOS Apache setup loads configuration directives from files placed in /etc/httpd/conf.d. Check if you have a file named /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.ini or something similar.

If you do, it probably means that you have additional version of PHP installed from RPM. Consider removing it to prevent additional conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Did you uninstall the php package from CentOS before doing the install of the new version? Also check where the /libphp5.so file was save after installing.

I'd recommend to install the PHP 5.2 rpm package from the recently released [Rackspace repository](http://iuscommunity.org/wp/) .

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `rpm -qa|grep php*`

```
rpm -qa|grep php*
libgphoto2-2.4.5-1.fc11.i586
hyphen-2.4-2.fc11.i586
phonon-backend-xine-4.3.1-6.fc11.i586
gvfs-gphoto2-1.2.3-12.fc11.i586
phonon-4.3.1-6.fc11.i586
xorg-x11-drv-elographics-1.2.3-2.fc11.i586
openoffice.org-graphicfilter-3.1.1-19.2.fc11.i586
hyphen-en-2.4-2.fc11.i586
```

You'll get some thing like this results then u can remove the rpm which you need to update or upgrade.

```
yum remove phonon-4.3.1-6.fc11.i586 -y
```

then you can check u r repo file at /etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo
then you can run

```
yum update -y
```

and

```
yum install phonon-5.3.1-6.fc11.i586 -y
```

it will work

Answer (score 0):

You have two lines that are including `libphp5.so` on your `httpd.conf`.  Just open it in your favourite editor and search for `php5`, and then keep searching till you find all instances of the line.

Make sure you are only loading the module you actually want to use - and of course, only once.

Once often gets this error if you are upgrading and you use the install process that came with the PHP that you are upgrading too, which tries to be nice and adds the include line for `libphp5.so` for you, but does not remove the pre-existing one because it is in a different place or for whatever reason it did not notice that it was in the file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check /etc/httd/conf.d directory. All configuration file ending with .conf are included to main apache configuration. This is a duplicate. Before compiling new PHP you should remove traces of old one using

```
yum remove php\*
```